# How to get dynamic path params from route in aiohttp when mocking the request?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, pytest, aiohttp

Using the below route definition, I am trying to extract the `book_id` out of the URL in aiohttp.

```
from aiohttp import web
routes = web.RouteTableDef()

@routes.get('/books/{book_id}')
async def get_book_pages(request: web.Request) -> web.Response:
    book_id = request.match_info.get('book_id', None)

    return web.json_response({'book_id': book_id})
```

Below is the test (using pytest) I have written

```
import asynctest
import pytest
import json

async def test_get_book() -> None:
    request = make_mocked_request('GET', '/books/1')
    response = await get_book(request)
    assert 200 == response.status
    body = json.loads(response.body)
    assert 1 == body['book_id']
```

Test Result:

```
None != 1

Expected :1
Actual   :None
```

Outside of the tests, when I run a request to `/books/1` the response is `{'book_id': 1}`

**What is the correct way to retrieve dynamic values from the path in aiohttp when mocking the request?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`make_mocked_request()` knows nothing about an application and its routes.

To pass dynamic info you need to provide a custom `match_info` object:

```
async def test_get_book() -> None:
    request = make_mocked_request('GET', '/books/1', 
                                         match_info={'book_id': '1'})
    response = await get_book(request)
    assert 200 == response.status
    body = json.loads(response.body)
    assert 1 == body['book_id']
```

**P.S.**

In general, I want to warn about mocks over-usage. Usually, [functional testing](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/testing.html#pytest) with `aiohttp_client` is easier to read and maintain.

I prefer mocking for really hard-to-rest things like network errors emulation.
Otherwise your tests do test your own mocks, not a real code.